# How to Create Account and get "Created" Response instead of "Completed" using Paypal Adaptive Accounts SDK

Tags: c#, paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

When I try to create account on behalf of my users by PayPal REST API, I get `execStatus` as `COMPLETED` which means that the account is not set up.

```
COMPLETED - The account creation request was successful, but the account holder must be redirected to finish setting up the account.
```

How can I create an account and get the `CREATED` response?

```
CREATED - Account creation is complete. No redirection is necessary to let the account holder finish setting up the account.
```

(at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/CreateAccount_API_Operation/)

At the very top of the page:

```
The CreateAccount API creates a PayPal account on behalf of the specified third party. The account can be a personal account, premier account, or business account.
```

I don't want my users to be redirected to PayPal. I will be getting their bank account information and add a bank account right after I create a PayPal account on behalf of them so they will be able to receive funds.

What I am trying to achieve is creating a PayPal account (without redirection) and adding a bank account to let them receive payments other users will make in the future.

I use `PayPalAdaptiveAccountsSDK`'s `public CreateAccountResponse CreateAccount(CreateAccountRequest createAccountRequest);` method.

PayPalAdaptiveAccountsSDK: https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-dotnet

How can I overcome this problem?